# Where should I store configuraton data?

Tags: php

I would like to store configuration data ( key value pairs ) which i will load in every request.

I know three methods, but I don't know, which is most professional way.

1. I store it in a table, where first column is the key, second is the value. And I run a `select * from table` when a browser request a page.
2. I create a JSON file, and store it there. Then read the json file, and parse JSON
3. I create a php file, and the key-value pairs will be in an `array()`, and just include it

Comment: BTW, Wordpress uses the third approach.

Comment: This appears to be primarily opinion based because there are advantages and disadvanatges to each option. And none is clearly "best"

Comment: you can use xml for store config file

Comment: How will you retrieve database connection data in step 1? To connect to that database you need those details?

Comment: @ThinkDifferent you could have a minimal config file for the database but keep everything else separate.

Comment: @TimSeguine I know that but there were three options mentioned in the question and database connection was included in all three (as I can see). For database connection option 1 is not possible.

Comment: only in the first one is database connection

Comment: @ThinkDifferent correct, I thought you were objecting to its use generally though.

Comment: Application configuration stored in a database table is a holdover from the mod_php era. Unless you seriously adapt settings every 5 minutes, using anything but an ini/php/json file is just adding needless inefficiency and complexity.

Comment: More prior discussions: [Best way to store a PHP App's Settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2368329), [how to store configurations for php app -- xml or ini or db](http://stackoverflow.com/q/798654), [What is the best way to store configuration variables in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/593440), [Difference in performance among config files for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8350584)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .ini files for config, and store it in non-accessable for visitors directory. 
For example:

```
/web
   index.php
   /images
/application
   /classes
   /config
      /config.ini
```

only `web` is public is directory

Answer (score 1):

You can prefer first option if you are allowing your site admin to change the options. This functionality is used in WordPress

You can prefer third option if you do not change the configurations with UI that is browser. For example, database connection details.

Second option does not seem practical.

Comment: The second option can be found "in the wild". It has the benefit/limitation of not allowing executable code in config files.

Comment: If the config file is JSON, then I can change and save it from PHP